# Help in this question in Fulton's algebraic curves

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, proof-verification, algebraic-curves

I'm trying to solve this question:

[image]

In item (a) I used the fact $O_a(V)$ is a Noetherian local ring and the only maximal ideal is $(x-a)$. First note that the non-units of $O_a(V)$ are the elements $h=\frac{f}{g}$ where $f(a)=0$, but $f(a)=0$ iff $x-a|f$ iff $f\in (x-a)$, then $O_a(V)$ is a DVR because it's a local ring with only one maximal ideal which is principal.

Am I right?

I need help in item (b).

If anyone could help me I would be very grateful

Thanks

Comment: For (a) you should also check that the maximal ideal is not nilpotent. For instance $\mathbf Z/p^2$ has only one prime ideal, which is principal, but it is not a DVR.

Comment: @BrunoJoyal I've already proved also that $O_a(V)$ is noetherian, $Z/P^2$ is noetherian? thanks for you comment

Comment: Of course, $\mathbf Z/p^2$ is noetherian, it's a finite ring!

Comment: @BrunoJoyal So $Z/P^2$ is DVR by Fulton's definition of DVR. Fulton defines a DVR as a Noetherian local ring such that the maximal ideal is principal

Comment: That definition is erroneous. There are many equivalent definitions of a DVR, and that is not one of them. He is missing something; either that the maximal ideal is not nilpotent, or that the ring have Krull dimension 1. Otherwise, according to his definition a field is a DVR, which is absurd. See definition 4 on the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_valuation_ring)

Comment: @BrunoJoyal ha yes, good remark, The ring has to be a domain such that it's not a field. see on page 22: http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Your solution for (a) looks OK to me, though it wouldn't hurt to justify that the non-units are what you claim.

For (b), here's a hint:  write
$$ \frac{f}{g} = \frac{1}{x} \cdot \frac{xf}{g} $$
What can you say about where the rhs lives if $\deg f < \deg g$?

What can you say about $f/g$ when $\deg f = \deg g$?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, What is rhs?

Comment: sorry, right hand side

Comment: I don't know, what I think I know is $\frac{xf}{g}$ is invertible, but I don't know why.